# How to get url and text values for ordered list

Tags: html-lists, selenium-ide

Whats the best way of getting the url and text values for an ordered list using Selenium IDE?

I've tried storeAllLink, store, storeTable, storeText but I haven't been able to get both the url and its display text then expand it out to do it for an ordered list

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing the code, but to my knowledge there isn't a function in selenium that can do what you need directly. The storealllinks command will just store the IDs of the links. Your best bet might be using storeHTMLSource and then using a regex to pull out any link target URLs and names.

Comment: Thanks @Jsmith2800 How do you use regex in selenium once you have the htmlsource stored in a variable?

Comment: I was refrain from doing anything with the entire html source where you can avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

It's ugly but this would work:
Using this page, http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_lists.asp,  as an example:

```
<tr>
    <td>storeEval</td>
    <td>this.browserbot.findElement('//div[@class=&quot;w3col w3-half&quot;][2]/ol').innerHTML</td>
    <td>orderedList</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>echo</td>
    <td>${orderedList}</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

> [info] Playing test case Untitled [info] Executing: |storeEval |
>   this.browserbot.findElement('//div[@class="w3col
>   w3-half"][2]/ol').innerHTML | orderedList | [info] script is:
>   this.browserbot.findElement('//div[@class="w3col
>   w3-half"][2]/ol').innerHTML [info] Executing: |echo | ${orderedList} |
>   | [info] echo:
>
> First item
>
> Second item
>
> Third item
>
> Fourth item
>
> [info] Test case
>   passed

This will pull out everything under the orderlist which was defined using our xpath locator.

You can use javascript in the store eval, if you need further manipulation but this will spell it out (although SO is formatting it as html, it is plain text)